# Still confused with $AX=0$ in homogeneous system. What is the next step?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to go from here:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & -1\\0 & 2 & -3\\0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

For nonhomogeneous $AX = B$ becomes $X = A^{-1}B$

For Homogeneous $AX = 0$ becomes $X = 0$? So will every homogeneous system get $0$ values for $x$?

I've read that sometimes it can be nontrivial solution which means $x \ne 0$... but this contradicts homogeneous systems with $AX = 0$ becoming $X = 0.$

Please help..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider $A$ being the zero matrix, for example; but your matrix clearly has non-zero determinant, so it's invertible

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Would you wish to have a graphical explanation for the system of equations? i.e. when they have only the trivial solution and when they have infinite solution.

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda if possible please,.. I really want to understand this

Comment: @WeitterKadenokouji Are you equipped with the knowledge of scalar triple product and 3d coordinate geometry?

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda sorry, I'm not. I haven't seen that in our discussions

Comment: @WeitterKadenokouji You just need to accept those things as a fact. It would develop your intuition for the topic. I am typing an answer.

Comment: @Soumyadwip Chanda thank you!

Comment: While true in your example, $A^{-1}$ does not exist in general. When $A$ is not invertible, there will be non-zero solutions to $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be any matrix equation $Ax=O$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

This can be simplified to get the following 3 equations
$$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=0$$
$$a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=0$$
$$a_3x+b_3y+c_3z=0$$

These are the equations of three planes passing through the origin.

Also, from the knowledge of 3D coordinate geometry, a vector perpendicular to the plane $ax+by+cz=d$ is parallel to $a\hat{i}+b\hat j+c\hat k$

Now, we have an operation on vectors known as scalar triple product, that gives us the volume of the parallelepiped formed by the three vectors as coterminus edges.

The scalar triple product of $a_i\hat i+b_i\hat j+c_i\hat k=0$ for $i=1,2 $ and $ 3$ is given by the determinant value of the matrix $A$. If $\mathrm{Det}(A)=0$, then all the three vectors lie in one plane (because volume of the parallelepiped will be 0).

When the vectors lie in a plane, then the planes perpendicular to them will intersect in a line. Ponder upon it or play with the following [here](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/cswnf8qz)

When they intersect in a line, then they have infinite solutions. Hence when $\mathrm{Det}(A)=0$, you have infinite solutions for $Ax=0$

If $\mathrm{Det}(A)\neq 0$ then they only intersect at the origin. So the trivial case is the only solution then.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This made me understand it clearer. I wish my professor explained it like you did. (Sorry for the late reply, I needed to finish a code earlier)

Comment: @WeitterKadenokouji Thanks for the appreciation. I always try to answer intuitively/graphically. You may check other answers of mine. :)

Comment: Will do definitely! You're very good at explaining :) Have a great day~

Answer (score 1):

I assume
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & -1\\0 & 2 & -3\\0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

here you referred to the homogeneous representation of 2D real space. In this case $X$ is the homogeneous representation of a point $(x,y)$ on 2D real space. Less confusion representation of your matrix equation would be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & -1\\0 & 2 & -3\\0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = 0$$
where $X = [x_1, x_2, x_3]^T$.
Now the relationship of the point $(x,y)$ to its homogeneous representation is as follows:
$x =x_1/x_3$ 
$y = x_2/x_3$

Therefore, for any point in real 2D point which is not infinity $x_3 \ne 0$ on the homogeneous space. Therefore, for any point not in infinity $X \ne 0$

Comment: Also, $(a,b)$ in the real 2D plane is usually represented on the homogeneous plane as $X = [a, b, 1]^T$

Comment: Wait I'll come back to this. And try to apply this to other given problems

Answer (score 0):

For a Homogeneous system, you could have $X=0$. No problem with it at all. When $X=0$ we say we have a "trivial" solution.

If you're looking for non-trivial solutions(infinite solutions), $A$ should be $0$ which isn't the case here. For the given set of equations in the question, only a trivial solution is possible.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of the matrix is the product of the diagonal entries, since it is upper triangular.  Thus the determinant equals $16$.  Since it isn't zero, the linear transformation is injective.  That means there is only one solution, zero, for the homogeneous system.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

System of  homogenous equations AX=0 is always consistent ( always solution exists ).
If the solution is unique then X=0 is the only solution.
Otherwise the system has infinitely many solutions other than X=0 (we say the system has non trivial solution).
Means in both case X=0 is a solution.

If A is invertible then we say solution is unique .So here X=0 is the only solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!